# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, deserialization, binaryformatter

I'm using BinaryFormatter to serialize/deserialize list of string on server/client.
But sometimes exception "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed" appears on client side during deserialization:

```
List<string> retrievedList = (List<string>)formatterDeserialize.Deserialize(reader.BaseStream);
```

Server code:

```
    var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipesEnroll", PipeDirection.InOut);
while (true)
{
        server.WaitForConnection();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(server);   
List<string> sendList = new List<string>();
  sendList.Add(isOk.ToString());
  sendList.Add(terminalTemplate);
  sendList.Add(matcherTemplate);
  sendList.Add(numberFingers.ToString());
  BinaryFormatter formatterSerialize = new BinaryFormatter();
  formatterSerialize.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, sendList);
  writer.Flush();
  server.Disconnect();
 }
```

Client code:

```
using (var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "PipesEnroll", PipeDirection.InOut))
          {
             client.Connect();
             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client);   
 BinaryFormatter formatterDeserialize = new BinaryFormatter();
    List<string> retrievedList =  (List<string>) formatterDeserialize.Deserialize(reader.BaseStream);
}
```

Exception details:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at CIS.BioTime.Manager.EmployeeWizardForm.SetTemplate_Impl(Int32 templateNumberX, ImageSet imageSet, IList`1 bitmapImages, Boolean& zkWarning, Boolean generateZKTemplateOnly) in d:\BioTime\trunk\REL_6.0.0\SOURCE\BioTime\CIS.BioTime.Manager\EmployeeWizardForm.Code.cs:line 1447
```

Does anybody have any suggestion on how to avoid this issue?